# Flutter iOS - Run script : xcode_backend.sh Operation not permitted

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I'm trying to build any Flutter app on iOS on a new Macbook pro 16"
My project used to work well, then after some flutter upgrade, i can't build any project with Xcode

Problem:

> /bin/sh:
> /Users/{MyUserName}/Documents/dev/utils/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh:
>
> Operation not permitted Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a
> nonzero exit code

What i tried:

- Upgrading Xcode & Command line tools
- chmod -R 755 my project, and the flutter lib
- Follow the Flutter tutorial to use flutter with the latest version of xcode
- Switching flutter channel (tried stable 1.17 & master 1.19)
- Delete Xcode (& dependencies) delete Flutter & reinstall both

Now, when i try to create a new flutter project
I always face the issue.
The builds are working when i use flutter run from CLI (on my device)
But if i try to use the project with xcode & try to build or run, i face the issue above.

I cant really find similar issues on the web.

PS: My project are working on my old macbook pro 13" same version of xcode and Flutter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the answer:

The problem was that Xcode App didn't have enough rights to read / write files & folders.

To solve it:

- Go to System preferences > Security & Privacy
- Last tab: Privacy
- Full disk access: Add Xcode App

If you dont want Xcode to have full disk access you can add it in "Files and folders" instead, and give Xcode rights to your projects folder

Comment: This is the correct answer, I can't thank you enough! I've been searching for hours and all I found was to disable the "UserScriptSandboxing" option. But that is only one part of the solution.